# processbuilder in Java to run a seqence of commands

Tags: java, processbuilder

Can I use the same ProcessBuilder object to run a sequence of commands in Java or
should I create a new ProcessBuilder object for each command??

Comment: Why don't you try it and see?

Comment: Currently I am using a different object for each command.I dont think it can be made into 1 object.was just confirming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you could take the time to read the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) you would know this. A `ProcessBuilder` can start multiple processes. (Sort of the point of having a `ProcessBuilder`.)